# How use correctly a .dll file in python on linux and mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, macos, dll

I have been trying to use a dll library from [CNES](https://logiciels.cnes.fr/en/content/propa) in python.
My first approach was trough `ctypes` and i did something like:

```py
from ctypes import *
cdll.LoadLibrary("dll/propa64.dll")
```

This simple loading goes very smooth on windows but i have trouble on mac/linux. More specifically when i try to run the code on MacOS i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-74c6935de494> in <module>
----> 1 cdll.LoadLibrary("dll/propa64.dll")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    440
    441     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 442         return self._dlltype(name)
    443
    444 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(dll/propa64.dll, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    dll/propa64.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
    /range/code_python/propa/dll/propa64.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

and in Linux(to be precise is a linux docker image on a macos host) i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-74c6935de494> in <module>
----> 1 cdll.LoadLibrary("dll/propa64.dll")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    440 
    441     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 442         return self._dlltype(name)
    443 
    444 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: dll/propa64.dll: invalid ELF header
```

Now it is preatty clear that there is some sort of incompatibility on Linux and Macos for this dll.
My question are:

1. why is that?
2. is there a way to make this library more "compatible" ?

I have been looking around a bit and maybe Cython could be useful but i'm not entirely sure.
Thank in advance for the help!

Someone pointed out this: [Importing a dll in python on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876225/importing-a-dll-in-python-on-ubuntu) but even though this could be a valid workaround i would rather prefer to solve the problem at is core.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a dll in python on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876225/importing-a-dll-in-python-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Well somehow yes but i would prefer to solve the problem at the root and get some less cumbersome stuffs

Comment: When the C code is compiled, it can only be executed on the platform it was compiled on. So a DLL library (compiled for Windows) is useless on Linux/MacOS, and vice versa. If you want to use the library on Linux, you need to download `propa64.so` and load it instead of the DLL file. On MacOS, you'd need a `propa64.dylib`, but it seems that the developer doesn't offer it, so your only possibility is to obtain the source code and compile it on MacOS yourself.

Comment: @hoefling thanks that was very helpful. I will try to contact the developer for the source code like also Basile Starynkevitch suggested. But for now windows and linux will be sufficent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling) explained, *.dll libraries are only for Windows.
At the site you've specified, there *already are* libraries built for and Linux.

[image]

The static lib `propa64.a` definitely should work on Linux, and I guess if it's for `x86` `64-bit` platform, it should also work on MacOS.

Comment: Both .a and .so works for linux (in my case a docker container on a mac host) unfortunately it does not with mac but for now windows and linux will do just fine. Thank you all for your help!