# Is there a way to use Window compiled dll into a python script in Ubuntu/linux system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ubuntu, dll

I have some windows ddl (no idea where they come from), and I would like to use them in a Python script running on Ubuntu. Does someone know if it is possible?

Comment: @KlausD. I have already seen that question, and since I did some research about the argument, I guess there are other way to solve the problem nowadays, Since 5 years passed from last answer.

Answer (score 0):

DLL libraries are very OS dependent, so that library built for windows cannot possibly work in unix like OS.

Ive use [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) for this type work.

More friendly Wine based platform [CrossOver](http://CrossOver.codeweavers.com), Ive use it for MacOS

Its already discussed at [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876225/importing-a-dll-in-python-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks @TimurU, Could you please tell me where can I find a tutorial or a guide regarding the use of dll with WINE? Looking around I found this github repo https://github.com/taviso/loadlibrary that seems to solve the problem. Have you seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

To use Windows DLLs inside a linux environment, you need an platform like [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/). It converts Win32 API calls to POSIX calls on the fly.

Comment: Thansk @Wasif Hasan Do you know a tool to directly use these POSIX calls in python or matlab script?