# How to load a dll in python under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dll, mono, wine, python.net

I would like to import a dll file under Ubuntu 20.04 in Python 3.8.

I tried it with mono and pythonnet as it was recommended in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648682/5426414):

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(dll_path)
import image3dAPI
```

but I got the following error:

> Invalid Image

If I check the dll with mono:

```
$ monop -r Image3dLoaderGe.dll
```

It says:

> Could not load Image3dLoaderGe.dll

Is there any other way to use this dll under Linux (even if it is not an "Assembly DLL file")?

I read about [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/), but I didn't find any sample code where they did something similar.

Comment: DLL is Windows format, look for SO for Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Few possible issues here:

1. there are several libs that goes by the import name clr. like IronPython (https://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/) or clr (https://pypi.org/project/clr/) - you need to make sure you install pythonnet (which is also imported with import clr) so install with: `pip install pythonnet`
2. the importing of the class from the lib should include the namespace, like so: `from <namespace> name import <class name>`. see pythonnet tutorial for more info: https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/
3. not all DLLs are supported in Linux. for example, if it's a C# DLL, it must be built with .NET core or else it would only work with Windows OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).